# "Air sac" and "air cell" in a chicken embryo

Tags: terminology, chickens

I need to translate the Russian term "воздушный мешок". It is part of the chicken embryo, marked by number 5 in the figure below.

> [image]

I found the expression **air cell** but also found the expression **air sac** in English. [On one site](https://www.beautyofbirds.com/stagesofincubation.html), "air sac" is described as a synonym to the "allantoic sac":

> [image]

Just to make sure: is **air cell** the only correct translation for the structure marked by number 5?

My sentence goes roughly like this:

> ...  the injections are made from the direction of the naturally-occuring **air cell** (?) so as to apply the material onto the chorioallantoic membrane (CAM).

Comment: air sac can also mean the air spaces created by outgrowth of the lung into the bones, which are part of the bird breathing mechanism. Air cell would this be less confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Atlas of Chick Development by Ruth Bellairs and Mark Osmond, a book I'm using for my developmental biology course :

> **Air space**  is the space between the two shell membranes at the blunt end of the egg. The chick pushes its beak into this space shortly before hatching and takes its first breathe of air.

Besides allantois is the extra embryonic membrane and the space enclosed by it is allantoic cavity.

Here label **2** is Allantoic cavity.

Comment: Thank you, Sanjukta! So "air cell" is also a miss, or it will be okay?

Comment: I can't assure you but from a google search the term air cell appears to be in use too.